# Looking up a value in a cell with multiple entries based off of a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet that has cells in it with multiple lines in each cell:

Cell A1 has

```
value A
value B
value C
value D
```

Cell A2 has

```
value B
value C
value D
```

Cell A3 has

```
value E
```

The table is on a different sheet and has the name COMP_VAL

```
value A
value E
```

I need to put an X in the Associated B column for each row that has a match in the table. Right now I have an IF with an OR and an IFERROR formula that looks like this

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(FIND(COMP_VAL!$A$1,A1),0),IFERROR(FIND(COMP_VAL!$A$2,A2),"X","")
```

So I will get an X in B1, no X in B2 and an X in B3.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: A single X in column B if any of the lines in column A match the compare to table.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=IF(SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH(COMP_VAL!$A$1:$A$2,A1),0)),"X","")
```

Depending on one's version of Excel this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Then drag down.

[image]